# spring multiactioncontroller command object

Tags: spring, object, command

Hei,

I am trying to get a command object in a class which extends a MultiActionController. The Controller class is:

```
public class RaspunsNouController extends MultiActionController
{   
    public ModelAndView submit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Response obj) throws Exception 
    {
       System.out.println("Submit method called");
       System.out.println(request.getParameter("username"));
       Response obiectR = (Response) obj;
       System.out.println(obiectR.getClass());
       System.out.println(obiectR.getAgence_response());
       System.out.println(obiectR.getResponse());
       return new ModelAndView("raspunsNou");
    }    
}
```

the important part of the jsp file is:

```
 <form:form  method="POST" commandName="response" style="position:relative; top:50px; left:100px; width:400px; border:2px red solid;" >
    <form:textarea path="response" />

    <br/><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='submit.htm'">Valider</button>
    <button type="button">Annuler</button>     
 </form:form>
```

And the error I am getting is :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'response' available as request attribute
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:532)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'response' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag.writeTagContent(TextareaTag.java:95)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.raspunsNou_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005ftextarea_005f0(raspunsNou_jsp.java:221)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.raspunsNou_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(raspunsNou_jsp.java:140)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.raspunsNou_jsp._jspService(raspunsNou_jsp.java:80)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I realise that I should do some binding somewhere (like in simpleFormController , in the formBackingObject method, but I don't know how or where).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a Object with name "response" in you model. Because your form expect it:
`<form:form  method="POST" commandName="response"`

```
   Response obiectR = (Response) obj;

   ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
   model.addAttribute("response", obiectR);
   return new ModelAndView("raspunsNou", model);
```

Form Spring Reference:

> The preceding JSP (`<form method="POST">...`) assumes that the variable name of the form backing object is 'command'. If you have put the form backing object into the model under another name (definitely a best practice), then you can bind the form to the named variable like so:
>   `<form:form commandName="user">`

So what you need to do is: put the command object with the name used in the jsp ("response") in the Model and return it via ModelAndView. You have to do it in all command method, that uses THE jsp to render.

It seams that you are using Spring 2.x, may you should have look at the SimpleFormController.

Comment: Can you please give me some more details?

Comment: When exactly did the error occur, and is the Command Method, the method that populate the form, or does the form "invoke" the method?

Comment: first time I load this page from another controller, this is the method (I tried putting what you told me here also):           public ModelAndView raspunsNou(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  
     
     ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
     modelMap.addAttribute("response","nimic" );
 
     return new ModelAndView("raspunsNou",modelMap);
 }

Comment: @Alexandra: I have extended my answer, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem isn't solved yet but I don't have that error anymore. I will try to get rid of the new one tomorrow and if not, I will ask again. Thanks again.